# Loading Different module from kernel/net/sched folder in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, kernel

I have noticed in the folder kernel/net/sched in ubuntu there are various `.ko` files (kernel modules) of various scheduling algorithms such as RED algorithm (`sch_red.ko`).

How to identify which module my kernel is using and is there a way to change to another module?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tc`. The following command will show which qdisc (queue discipline) is being used currently:

```
# tc qdisc show
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev eth0 root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
qdisc mq 0: dev wlan0 root
```

You can `modprobe` the `sch_red` module and then try to enable it as described in `red(8)`.
Also take a look at the [Traffic control HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/).

Comment: So to add Red Algorithm will this command work?:

tc qdisc add    
>                  dev eth0     \ 
>                  root         \ 
>                  handle 1:0   \ 
>                  sch_red.ko